# Android add up arrow to float Activity

Tags: android

i have this activity before float it

[image]

how can i add up arrow when float it and when back to none floating remove the up arrow

[image]

did i must change the `setContentView` when i float it with different style or there are another method

Comment: Use some view which contains the ImageButton for example, and set it's visibility programmatically to VISIBLE and GONE at appropriate times.

Comment: @Vucko i cant do it i make `FrameLyout` with image View and i give it -20dp margin top when i run application its not shown because its outside the container layout

Comment: Well I don't know how you thought that it can be outside of the layout :D

Comment: @Vucko just like facebook messenger there are arrow but how can i do like it did u have any example ? |B

Comment: No man, sorry, I've never done that before :/